# How to add scope for facebook never expires token

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I have trouble with adding the scope for facebook never expires token.

I have the ruby application that generated non-expiry token already, by using the omniauth. Now I want to add the additional scope("read_insights") to the existing token, and went through the same oauth flow. However, looks like facebook still returns the original token without the additional scope, maybe because the original token never expires. Do you know how to create the new token?

Comment: you have to go through the whole oauth flow again for additional permissions.  The token is unique each time

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I needed to add "read_insights" permission to the facebook app also.